# C++ Issue when removing node from linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a remove function for a linked list, but I'm getting some strange results. Any time I remove a node that isn't the final one in the list, I can display the list data up until the node that was removed. After that, I get one random set of data, and the program ends.

In the code below, if I take out the "delete t;" line, everything works as expected, but as soon as I add the "delete t;" line back in, it goes back to the odd behavior I've been seeing. I've tried moving around where I set t equal to head, or where I delete t, but I get the same result regardless of what I do.

```
void List::remove(int d) {
    Node *t, *prev;
    if (!head) return;
    t = head;
    if (head->data == d) {      
        head = head->next;
        delete t;
    }
    else {
        while (t != nullptr && t->data != d) {
            prev = t;
            t = t->next;
        }
        if (t) {
            prev->next = t->next;
            delete t;
        }
        else {
            cout << "value not found" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a for loop to insert integers 0-9 into the list. If I then try to remove the node containing the number 5, I get the following output when trying to display the remaining data:

0

1

2

3

4

-572662307

Press any key to continue...

Where I'm expecting:

0

1

2

3

4

6

7

8

9

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin He is maintaining ```prev```, ```current```, ```next``` pointers. He has ```prev``` and ```t```. Here ```t``` is ```current``` pointer. And before *deleting* he used ```t->next``` which is ```next``` pointer here. I don't think anything wrong here.

Comment: @FarukHossain so he is... Using descriptive names like `victim` instead of `t` makes things much more readable. The error is elsewhere in his code. Good catch.

Comment: You keep processing after the `delete t;`.  Presumably you just want to return then, since the `head` case does only the one removal.